# ¿Cómo extraer datos en base a un id desde Firebase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

Este es parte de mi Json de firebase:

```
{
"Bencina" : [ {
"UserAdmin" : "Dagg",
"fechaPublicacion" : "Wed Nov 30 2016 21:03:48 GMT-0300",
"idBencinera" : 1,
"idCiudad" : "1",
"nombreBencinera" : "Copec",
"ubicacionBencinera" : "calle"
}, {
"UserAdmin" : "Dagg",
"fechaPublicacion" : "Wed Nov 30 2016 21:03:48 GMT-0300",
"idBencinera" : 2,
"idCiudad" : "2",
"nombreBencinera" : "Shell",
"ubicacionBencinera" : "calle"
}, {
"UserAdmin" : "Dagg",
"fechaPublicacion" : "Wed Nov 30 2016 21:03:48 GMT-0300",
"idBencinera" : 3,
"idCiudad" : "3",
"nombreBencinera" : "Otra",
"ubicacionBencinera" : "calle"
}, {
"UserAdmin" : "Dagg",
"fechaPublicacion" : "Wed Nov 30 2016 21:03:48 GMT-0300",
"idBencinera" : 1,
"idCiudad" : "4",
"nombreBencinera" : "Copec",
"ubicacionBencinera" : "calle"
}, {
"UserAdmin" : "Dagg",
"fechaPublicacion" : "Wed Nov 30 2016 21:03:48 GMT-0300",
"idBencinera" : 2,
"idCiudad" : "5",
"nombreBencinera" : "Shell",
"ubicacionBencinera" : "calle"
 }
}
```

y lo que necesito es buscar los datos que yo quiera, pero en base al id de la ciudad, espero alguien sepa, ya que yo no he encontrado información, o no he buscado lo suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno tienes un arreglo JSON

lo mejor seria recorrerlo

```
var ciudadId = 1;
var Bencinera;
$.each(arreglo, function (index, value) {
    $.each(value, function (index, dato) {
        if(dato.idCiudad == ciudadId){
             Bencinera = dato;
        }   
    });
});
console.log(Bencinera.nombreBencinera);
console.log(Bencinera.UserAdmin);
```

Comment: esto lo ya lo habia pensado, gracias

Comment: y no te funciono? que es lo que esperas entonces

Comment: no lo he probado en eso estoy, pense que como firebase tiene sus propios metodos , tendria alguno propio

Comment: tengo un problemas, no he visto nunca ese $.each, no se como usarlo y que hace??

Comment: Es basicamente un foreach como de otro lenguaje, tu pasas un arreglo (que seria el que recibes de firebase) separa su respuesta entee index (index del arreglo) y object (como un objeto de ese arreglo) en este caso arreglo es un arreglo CON arreglos dentro, por lo tanto el segundo each recorre esos arreglos, dato vendria a ser Bencinera que es un elemento de un arreglo.

Comment: @Dagg  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1):

```
function (item) {
        // Esta linea es la que nos interesa
        this.myRootRef.child("users").child(item.idCiudad).set(item);
    }
```

Lo que hacemos en estas lineas de código es pasar un objeto llamado item que contiene la siguiente estructura por ejemplo.

```
UserAdmin : "Dagg"
fechaPublicacion" : "Wed Nov 30 2016 21:03:48 GMT-0300"
idBencinera : 1
idCiudad : "1"
nombreBencinera : "Copec"
ubicacionBencinera : "calle"
```

Leer datos en el servicio:

```
render: function(){
        var html="";
        this.myRootRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            var usuarios = snapshot.val();
            //Utilizamos un each de la librería underscore
            _.each(usuarios['users'], function(v, i){
                console.log(v.idCiudad);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: este no lo entiendo mucho, creo no entenderlo